# How to get compilation error in Jenkins for a code error without running the code?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

The trouble I am facing is:

Say, I have a JAVA code and I intentionally put a syntax error there, then the compilation should make the build fail.

Similarly, if there's no error, the compilation should mark the build as success.

BUT the catch is, I don't want to run the code. I just want this Failure and Success based on compilation

I have written a TestNg code for an automated test and I am using this maven goal in Jenkins:
`clean compile test`

This starts running the whole test and then brings the error on whichever line it's caught.

But I want to get this error during the compilation without running the test code.

Comment: If you want to break the build if there are compilation errors before you run any tests, then do the build in two steps. first `mvn compile` then `mvn test`.

Comment: Actually, I did the same thing but `mvn compile` doesn't detect the code error

Comment: Thanks, Andrey! Your ones is the exact solution of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try catching the error and killing the maven process from the jenkins  pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Compile') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn compile'
            }
            post {
                failure {
                    script {
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                        sh 'pkill -f "mvn compile"'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Seenukarthi and Tudorlftimie. This pipeline code is cherry at the top